# How to bind a dynamic Object with v-bind in vue

Tags: vue.js

I would like to ask a question of v-bind dynamic object. When binding is a completely dynamic object, how to bind properties with operation expression? How do I keep the attr observable? thank you！

```html
<template>
    <component v-bind="dynamicAttrs"></component>
</template>
```

```js
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                someObject:{
                    a:{
                        b:10
                    }
                },
                // This dynamicAttrs object is dynamically defined and save into the mysql database by the secondary development user, 
                // will load it from mysql for component init. 
                // All the properties of this object are dynamic, that is, how many properties are there, and the name of the property is dynamic.
                dynamicAttrs:{  
                    someAttr1:123,
                    someAttr2:"someObject.a.b + 500"   // How does this object with operation expressions bind? How do I ensure that it gets updated responsively, so that component gets the update automatically when `someobject.a.b` updated
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The dynamicAttrs object is dynamically defined and save into the mysql database by the secondary development user, load it from mysql for component init.

How does this object with operation expressions bind? How do I ensure that it gets updated responsively, so that component gets the update automatically when `someobject.a.b` updated

Answer (score 2):

Typically you'd use a computed property for this:

```js
computed: {
  dynamicAttrs () {
    return {
      someAttr1: 123,
      someAttr2: this.someObject.a.b + 500
    }
  }
}
```

If `someObject.a.b` updates the computed property will be re-evaluated and the bindings will be updated.

Comment: Sorry for confusing ,The `dynamicAttrs` object is dynamically defined and save into the mysql database by the secondary development user, load it from mysql for component init. So, I can't just use like `computed`.

Comment: @JacdyXu That shouldn't be a problem. The data from the server would be in a `data` property and the computed property would pull in whatever it needs. If you're actually trying to save expressions in the database as strings then you've got major design decisions to address.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please help to show me a sample let me know how to convert a JSON to computed? Thanks again.